# Не обрабатывает событие xhr.onprogress

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Не обрабатывает событие xhr.onprogress, передаю метод, который описан внутри класса

```
class UploaderFile {
    xhr;
    start_time;
    old_time;
    speeds;
    old_loaded;

    constructor(key, input) {
        this.start_time = new Date();
        this.old_time = new Date();
        this.speeds = [];
        this.old_loaded = 0;

        this.csrftoken = this.getCookie('csrftoken');

        this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        this.xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', this.updateProgress, false);
        this.xhr.addEventListener('load', this.transferComplete, false);
        // this.xhr.onprogress = this.updateProgress


        this.xhr.open('POST', 'upload_files', true);
        this.xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

        this.formData = new FormData();
        this.formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', this.csrftoken);
        this.key = key;
        this.input = input;
        this.formData.append(key, input);
    }

    send() {
        this.xhr.send(this.formData);
    }

    transferComplete(e) {
        let speed_avg;
        $.each(this.speeds, function (speed) {
            speed_avg = speed + speed_avg;
        });
        this.speed_avg = speed_avg / this.speeds.length
        console.log('comlid')
    }

    updateProgress(e) {
        console.log('upload')
    }

    draw_percent(percent) {
        let class_element = 'alert-message';
        let form = $('#upload_form');

        let in_form = $('<div>', {
            'class': class_element,
            text: 'Новый текст сообщения.'
        });
        let progress_bar = $('<progress>', {

        });
        if (form.find(in_form.className) <= 0) {
            form.append(in_form)
        };

        if (in_form.find(progress_bar) <= 0){
            form.append(progress_bar)
        };

        progress_bar.val(percent);
        console.log(progress_bar.val());

        in_form.css('border', '1px solid black');

    }

    getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                let cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
}
```

Единственное что могу предположить - внутри класса XMLHttpRequest не правильно ссылается на методы моего класса

Comment: Так не пробовали: `this.xhr.addEventListener('progress', this.updateProgress, false)`? Подробней [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/progress_event).

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло, но варианты

`this.xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', this.updateProgress, false);`

`this.xhr.onprogress = this.updateProgress`

прекрасно работали вне класса, почему так?

Comment: В этом случае создайте новый вопрос, где приведите код без использования класса и с использованием. В спецификации вариант `this.xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress'...` не используется.  `this.xhr.onprogress = this.updateProgress` - работать должен. Сказать что-то без кода затруднительно.

Comment: @XelaNimed, Ваш вариант с `this.xhr.addEventListener('progress', this.updateProgress, false)` не совсем подходит так как он вызывает функцию один раз, когда файл загружен на 100%,
но почему-то вариант с `this.xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', this.updateProgress, false);` заработал, но я не могу использовать поля и методы своего класса в `updateProgress` или `transferComplete`
Как я уже говорил, мне кажется из за того что эти функции вызываются в классе `XMLHttpRequest ` и "_Обработчик JS в браузере_" ищет их именно в этом классе

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Имеется небольшой танец с бубном и в первоначальный вариант с xhr.upload.addEventListener был в нужном направлении. На enSO уже обсуждался [такой-же вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3352555/3129992).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в том что `XMLHtmlRequest.upload.addEventListener` или `XMLHtmlRequest.addEventListener` в будущем передаёт второй аргумент в класс `XMLHtmlRequestUpload`.
По этому нужно передавать во второй аргумент анонимную функцию, которая будет принимать ProgressEvent и вызывать уже метод нашего класса. Таким образом можно передать ссылку на наш объект.

Пример:

```
this.xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', (e) => this.updateProgress(e, this), false);
```

Ну и сам метод:

```
updateProgress(e, parent) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(parent);
}
```

И аналогично с `transferComplete`